Second-Order Perturbation Correction for Helium atom
I am trying to calculate the second order perturbation correction for helium atom:
$$E^{(2)}_n = \sum^\infty_{i, i \neq n} \frac{|\langle \Psi_n | V | \Psi_i \rangle|^2}{E_n - E_i}$$
with the unperturbed ground-state wave function and for energy level $n$ from our results in Hydrogen atom:
$$\Psi^{(0)}_1 (\mathbf{r_1, r_2}) = \frac{Z^3}{\pi a^3_0} e^{\frac{-Z(r_1 + r_2)}{a_0}} \\ \Psi^{(0)}_n (\mathbf{r_1, r_2}) = \frac{64(2l+1)(n-l-1)! (l-m)!}{\pi^2 a^6_0 n^4 (l+m)! ((n+l)!)^3} \exp[2im \phi - \frac{(r_1 + r_2)}{a_0} (1 + \frac{1}{n})] \left(\frac{2(r_1 + r_2)}{na_0}\right)^l L^{2l+1}_{n-l-1} (\frac{2r_1}{na_0}) L^{2l+1}_{n-l-1} (\frac{2r_2}{na_0}) (P^m_l (cos \theta))^2.$$
From the Hydrogen atom results, the unperturbed energy for an energy level n is given by:
$$E^{(0)}_n = \frac{2Z^2 E_1}{n^2} = \frac{8E_1}{n^2}$$
so the quantity $E^{(0)}_1 - E^{(0)}_n$ is given by:
$$E^{(0)}_1 - E^{(0)}_n = 8E_1 \left[1-\frac{1}{n^2} \right].$$
Hence, the relation becomes:
$$E^{(2)}_n = \frac{1}{8E_1} \sum^\infty_{i, i \neq 1} \frac{|\int \Psi^{(0)}_1 V \Psi^{(0)}_i |^2}{(1-\frac{1}{i^2})}$$
which is complicated integrals with infinite sum, does anyone know how to solve this numerically or using codes for simplification?

Why do you have $r_1$ and $r_2$ but only a single $\theta$ and $\phi$?

You haven’t shown what $V$ is.

I am sorry, V is the electron-electron repulsion term $\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|}$

If we add two $\theta$ and $\phi$, it doesn't change the fact that I don't know yet how to solve it . It was a mistake that I forgot them.

I’m not sure how to do it, but I would try expanding $V$ in Legendre polynomials and then using the orthogonality of Legendre polynomials.

Isn’t that how you calculate the first-order term?

No, the first order correction is given by: $E^{(1)} = \langle \psi^{(0)}_1 | V |  \psi^{(0)}_1 \rangle$, the difficulty of second order term arises from existence of associated Legendre and associated laguerre, and the infinite sum over states.
